# Previous image effect while switching

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I am using QGraphicsScene to display video. I have two modes in which two different videos are shown. I am using a QGraphicsPixmapItem and displaying the video on it. When I switch from one video to other it does not show the latest frame immediately. For 2 or 3 seconds the last seen image for that view is visible. I have tried using removeItem() and delete for removing the pixmap items every time I switch the views but it is not helping. Can some one suggest me how to solve this?

```
//Member variables
 QGraphicsPixmapItem *m_pixItemZoomTrue;
 QGraphicsPixmapItem *m_pixItemZoomFalse;
 QGraphicsScene m_sceneZoomTrue;
 QGraphicsScene m_sceneZoomFalse;

//Slot called on button click

  void ZoomSelectionTrue()
  {
    //Remove the item from scene of ZoomSelectionFalse
    m_sceneZoomFalse->removeItem(m_pixItemZoomFalse);

    //Add item to the scene of ZoomSelectionTrue
    m_pixItemZoomTrue = new QGraphicsPixItem();
    m_sceneZoomTrue->addItem(m_pixItemZoomTrue);

   //Rest code for adding pixmap to the pix item.
  }

  void ZoomSelectionFalse()
  {
    m_sceneZoomTrue->removeItem(m_pixItemZoomTrue);
    m_pixItemZoomFalse = new QGraphicsPixItem();
    m_sceneZoomFalse->addItem(m_pixItemZoomFalse);

     //Rest code for adding pixmap to the pix item. 
  }
```

Thank You.

Comment: Perhaps, if you can show example code of what you're doing, we'd be in a better position to help you here, rather than just trying to guess at the cause of the problem.

Comment: Should one of those functions be called ZoomSelectionFalse? Also, which part of the code switches "from one video to the to the other" - is that the call to ZoomSelection... ?

Comment: It is alternate. At a time any one of the mode will be on. There are two different pages in a stacked widget and based on the button click the page shows up. Ohh yes sorry one of the function should be ZoomSelectionFalse. Extremely sorry for that.

Comment: Why do you need to keep creating a new pixmap? Can't you just setup the scene for each page, with the relevant pixmap and switch pages? If you want to stop the pixmap showing, just call setHidden(true).